# How can I read and remove meta (exif) data from my photos using the command line?

Tags: command-line, privacy, jpeg

Just looked this up. Figure I'd share it here for future reference.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312754/how-to-strip-metadata-from-image-files | don't recode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654281/how-to-remove-exif-data-without-recompressing-the-jpeg | location only: https://askubuntu.com/questions/236455/how-can-you-delete-only-gps-metadata-from-a-jpeg-file

Comment: `sudo apt-get install exiv2` and then `exiv2 rm *.jpg`

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Install exiftool:

```
sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

To read photo metadata:

```
exiftool /tmp/my_photo.jpg
```

To erase photo metadata:

```
exiftool -all= /tmp/my_photo.jpg
```

Before:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 8.60
File Name                       : my_photo.jpg
Directory                       : /tmp
File Size                       : 3.0 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2013:02:24 12:08:10-08:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : JPEG
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
Orientation                     : Unknown (0)
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Centered
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Modify Date                     : 2013:02:24 11:25:27
Make                            : Samsung
Camera Model Name               : Galaxy Nexus
Exif Version                    : 0220
Flashpix Version                : 
Color Space                     : sRGB
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Compressed Bits Per Pixel       : 0
Exif Image Width                : 1944
Exif Image Height               : 2592
Date/Time Original              : 2013:02:24 11:25:27
Create Date                     : 2013:02:24 11:25:27
Exposure Time                   : 1/354
F Number                        : 2.8
Exposure Program                : Aperture-priority AE
ISO                             : 50, 0, 0
Shutter Speed Value             : 1/353
Aperture Value                  : 2.6
Brightness Value                : 0
Exposure Compensation           : 0
Max Aperture Value              : 2.6
Subject Distance                : 0 m
Metering Mode                   : Multi-spot
Light Source                    : Daylight
Flash                           : No Flash
Focal Length                    : 3.4 mm
Flash Energy                    : 0
Exposure Index                  : undef
Sensing Method                  : One-chip color area
Scene Type                      : Directly photographed
Custom Rendered                 : Custom
Exposure Mode                   : Auto
White Balance                   : Auto
Digital Zoom Ratio              : 1
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Contrast                        : Normal
Saturation                      : Normal
Sharpness                       : Normal
Subject Distance Range          : Unknown
Image Unique ID                 : OAEL01
GPS Time Stamp                  : 19:25:27
GPS Date Stamp                  : 2013:02:24
Compression                     : JPEG (old-style)
Thumbnail Offset                : 2143
Thumbnail Length                : 10941
Image Width                     : 1944
Image Height                    : 2592
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Aperture                        : 2.8
GPS Date/Time                   : 2013:02:24 19:25:27Z
Image Size                      : 1944x2592
Shutter Speed                   : 1/354
Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 10941 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Focal Length                    : 3.4 mm
Light Value                     : 12.4
```

After:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 8.60
File Name                       : my_photo.jpg
Directory                       : /tmp
File Size                       : 2.9 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2013:02:24 12:21:39-08:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : JPEG
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
Image Width                     : 1944
Image Height                    : 2592
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Image Size                      : 1944x2592
```

References:

- http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/howto-strip-jpeg-metadata/
- http://hacktux.com/read/remove/exif
- [http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/%7Ephil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html)

Comment: To process all files in the current directory:  
`for f in *.jpg; do exiftool -all= "$f"; done`

Comment: or just `exiftool *.jpg`

Comment: You probably don't want to delete all EXIF metadata. For example, the "Orientation" piece of metadata rotates the photo. If you remove it, then the photos will appear to be rotated in the wrong way.

Comment: @pablo-bianchi I reverted your edit because security vulnerability info isn't really relevant to the question and somewhat ephemeral. Here's the link to the CVE alert that was removed: https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-22204

Answer (score 43):

### [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/)

Instead of [Exiftool](https://exiftool.org/), to handle [Exif metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) (IPTC, XMP and ICC image metadata also) I found [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/) (install it with `sudo apt install imagemagick`) more useful and command easier to remember.

[Since IMv7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/4970442) `magick identify/mogrify/...` it's used instead <sup>[[1]](https://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli)</sup>.

#### To read

```
identify -verbose image.jpg | grep exif
```

#### To remove

With `imagemagick` package installed you can do this (**not only for JPEGs**):

```sh
mogrify -strip *.jpg  # Optionally: -verbose
```

From [manual](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#strip):

> **`-strip`** strip the image of any profiles, comments or these PNG chunks: bKGD, cHRM, EXIF, gAMA, iCCP, iTXt, sRGB, tEXt, zCCP, zTXt, date.

Since you will lose the orientation metadata, maybe you'll want to `mogrify -auto-orient image.jpg` first.

[AFAIK](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=afaik) the only difference with exiftool is that `mogrify` won't remove this metadata:

- [JFIF Version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format)
- Resolution Unit
- X Resolution
- Y Resolution

Which might be useful. Compared with `diff -y <(exiftool wMogrify.jpg) <(exiftool wExiftool.jpg)`

**Remove EXIF data is not the same as anonymize**: [`-strip` will recompress the image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260810/how-can-i-read-and-remove-meta-exif-data-from-my-photos-using-the-command-line/968598?noredirect=1#comment1955203_968598). **This might be a good thing**: The same software that take the photo (or other) could hide sensitive information (which may be encrypted) inside of ordinary image data ([steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography)). I'm not sure if the recompression will always remove everything (probably not). To avoid this recompression you can use [jpegtran](https://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/):

```
jpegtran -copy none image.jpg > newimage.jpg
```

Also, to [avoid losing color profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17516878/4970442) ([ICC metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile), which causes richer colors<sup>[[citation needed]](https://xkcd.com/285/)</sup>):

```
convert image.jpg profile.icm && convert image.jpg -strip -profile profile.icm newimage.jpg
```

You might ask yourself if these costs are [noticeable or relevant](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10895) in your case.

Another tool about steganography on images is **[steghide](http://steghide.sourceforge.net/)**.

### Other tools and notes

- [**mat2**](https://0xacab.org/jvoisin/mat2) (Metadata anonymization toolkit v2): Removes metadata from **a lot** of formats (`--list`). It's recommended by [privacyguides.org](https://www.privacyguides.org/software/productivity/#metadata-removal-tools).
- **Alternatives**: [**`jhead`**](https://www.sentex.net/%7Emwandel/jhead/usage.html) ([**only** for JPEGs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312754/how-to-strip-metadata-from-image-files#comment834859_312946)) and [exiv2](https://github.com/Exiv2/exiv2) ([man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/exiv2.1.html); suggested [on Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Exif#Linux/Unix_users)).
- [Metadata Cleaner](https://metadatacleaner.romainvigier.fr/): Desktop app to view and clean metadata in files (not only images).
- If you prefer [Exiftool](https://exiftool.org/), you might find useful [creating an alias](https://askubuntu.com/a/17538/349837) to `exiftool -all= *.jpg && rm *original`, or with `-overwrite_original` option. To [remove only GPS data](https://askubuntu.com/a/237892/349837) use `exiftool -gps:all= -xmp:geotag= *.jpg`. Use an updated version: [CVE-2021-22204](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-22204).
- [**WebP format**](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/): [`webp`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&keywords=webp) package provides [`webpmux` command](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/webpmux.1.html), which *manage XMP/EXIF metadata and ICC profile*.
- [`exifprobe`](https://github.com/hfiguiere/exifprobe)/`exifgrep`: probe and report structure and metadata content of camera image files
- For Android? [Scrambled Exif](https://gitlab.com/juanitobananas/scrambled-exif), available on F-Droid (and Google Play).

#### See also

- [Harry Potter and the Digital Fingerprints | Electronic Frontier Foundation](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2007/07/harry-potter-and-digital-fingerprints)
- [A Picture is Worth a Thousand Words, Including Your Location | Electronic Frontier Foundation](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2012/04/picture-worth-thousand-words-including-your-location)
- [#facebook is embedding tracking data inside photos you download](https://twitter.com/oasace/status/1149181539000864769)

Comment: Note however that this appears to recompress the image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654281/how-to-remove-exif-data-without-recompressing-the-jpeg

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心996ICU六四事件I edited the answer. That' might be a good thing, to remove metadata encoded on the image. Would be great to have studies to support this.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this because the image size had changed considerably, but there must be better ways, at least in 2010 ImageMagick devs confirmed it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654281/how-to-remove-exif-data-without-recompressing-the-jpeg/2654452#2654452

Comment: Note that `mogrify -strip *.jpg` does remove the "Orientation" piece of metadata. Photos may appear to be rotated the wrong way without this piece of metadata. Same thing for `jpegtran -copy none example.jpg > out.jpg`

Answer (score 7):

To remove then change a single field we can use this command:

```
exiftool -Copyright= IMG_3357.jpg
exiftool -Copyright=LinuxSlaves IMG_3357.jpg
```

[Reference](http://www.linuxslaves.com/2015/05/view-and-manipulate-exif-metadata-image.html)

Answer (score 5):

I wish to add `mat2` which support not only images. It's recommended by [privacyguides.org](https://www.privacyguides.org/en/data-redaction/) (formerly known as *privacytools.io*) community.

> MAT2 is free software, which allows the removal of metadata of image,
> audio, torrent, and document file types. It provides both a command
> line tool and a graphical user interface via an extension for
> Nautilus, the default file manager of GNOME.

and

> [mat2](https://0xacab.org/jvoisin/mat2) is a metadata removal tool, supporting a wide range of commonly
> used file formats, written in python3: at its core, it's a library,
> used by an eponymous command-line interface, as well as several file
> manager extensions.

```
sudo apt install mat2
```

in-place purge of metadata

```
mat2 --inplace xxx.mp4
mat2 --inplace xxx.png
```

Comment: `-s` simply shows the metadata. You need to use `--inplace` to delete it. You can also use `-L` to remove some of the metadata. Refer to the [man pages](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/mat2/mat2.1.en) for more information

Comment: Looks like they changed the URL: https://www.privacyguides.org/en/data-redaction/

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of tools for this, as others have listed. One more that I found on my system is `exiv2`.

Install: `sudo apt-get install exiv2`
View: `exiv2 myimage.jpg`
Remove: `exiv2 rm myimage.jpg`

Additional options are listed in the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/exiv2.1.html).

Comment: Note that `exiv2 rm myimage.jpg` seems to remove the "orientation" metadata. This will make the resulting image appear to be rotated the wrong way in some cases.