# Is there a tool for removing metadata?

Tags: metadata

the title says it all. is there a tool?

I installed  ExifTool, but can't find a way to remove all at once with one command.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/260810/how-can-i-read-and-remove-meta-exif-data-from-my-photos-using-the-command-line

Answer (score 27):

```
exiftool -all= inputfile
```

The latest version of exiftool supports most file formats.

**Output:**

1. If the input file contained metadata, it removes the metadata and *overwrites* `inputfile`, but saves a copy of the original as `inputfile_original` in the same folder.
2. If the input file did not contain metadata, it performs no changes.

There are options in ExifTool to delete the original file: `-overwrite_original` and `-overwrite_original_in_place`.

Comment: Easy to make a mistake, do note the =

Comment: Be careful, this only hides data and does not delete it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/308250/is-there-a-tool-for-removing-metadata/1331315#1331315

Comment: @baptx regarding PDF files, that is.

Comment: @jarno indeed, at least for PDF files it was not enough but maybe there are also other file formats where using exiftool alone is not enough.

Comment: @baptx, yes, hard to know.

Answer (score 10):

The Metadata anonymisation toolkit would do the trick for you. It has a GUI as well.

After [Enabling the Universe Repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install mat
```

Comment: Doesn't support PDF files.

Comment: currently `apt install mat` actually installs the `mat2` command. [Here's its canonical repository](https://0xacab.org/jvoisin/mat2). It's easy to use, just `mat2 foo.jpg`.

Comment: @Foreever it supports PDF files but compared to the combination of exiftool / qpdf, it does the PDF export as an image, which is less nice / accessible than a PDF that contains text that you can copy-paste. Maybe they do this on purpose so people cannot guess the date / software version used based on the PDF structure.

Comment: I asked the author of mat2, he said it is possible to use text instead of images with the lightweight mode (-L option: https://0xacab.org/jvoisin/mat2#notes-about-the-lightweight-mode) but it will not clean metadata of embedded resources like images (https://0xacab.org/jvoisin/mat2/-/blob/master/doc/implementation_notes.md#lightweight-cleaning-mode).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is a tool to remove metadata called [exiv2](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/exiv2.1.html).

Usage: `exiv2 rm /path/to/location/files`

Comment: thanks for the answer. but thats only for images, right?

Comment: @aaaa yes my friend.

Answer (score 6):

When using the command `exiftool -all= inputfile` shared here on PDF files, I got this message:

> Warning: [minor] ExifTool PDF edits are reversible. Deleted tags may
> be recovered!

And by looking for the error message on a search engine, I found https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=4722.0 with a link to https://exiftool.org/TagNames/PDF.html that mentions:

> All metadata edits are reversible. While this would normally be
> considered an advantage, it is a potential security problem because
> old information is never actually deleted from the file. (However,
> after running ExifTool the old information may be removed permanently
> using the "qpdf" utility with this command: "qpdf --linearize in.pdf
> out.pdf".)

So if you really want to delete the metadata from PDF files so it cannot be recovered instead of just hiding it, you should use the command `qpdf --linearize in.pdf out.pdf` afterwards.

If you want to try to recover the hidden / removed metadata from PDF files, the man page https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html explains how to do it:

> Changes to PDF files by ExifTool are reversible (by deleting the
> update with -PDF-update:all=) because the original information is
> never actually deleted from the file. So ExifTool alone may not be
> used to securely edit metadata in PDF files.

So the command will be something like `exiftool -PDF-update:all= inputfile`. You can then check the properties of the file in your PDF viewer to see if the metadata is restored.

Note: this solution does not clean metadata of embedded resources like images unlike the tool `mat2` shared in another answer (except when using lightweight mode: https://0xacab.org/jvoisin/mat2/-/blob/master/doc/implementation_notes.md#lightweight-cleaning-mode). But images metadata is not always present in PDF files. For example to do a PDF export with LibreOffice Writer and keep metadata, we need to disable "Reduce image resolution" (an answer also mentioned that we need to enable "Lossless compression" but I did not need it: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/185507/does-embedding-images-in-pdf-retain-metadata).
Then I was able to save the image with metadata from the PDF file with LibreOffice Draw and view the metadata with GIMP in the menu "Image -> Metadata -> View Metadata".

Answer (score 4):

You can use Metadata Extraction Tool

> The Metadata Extract Tool includes a number of 'adapters' that extract
>   metadata from specific file types. Extractors are currently provided
>   for:
>
> - Images: BMP, GIF, JPEG and TIFF.
> - Office documents: MS Word (version 2, 6), Word Perfect, Open Office    (version 1), MS Works, MS Excel, MS PowerPoint, and PDF.
> - Audio and Video: WAV, MP3 (normal and with ID3Tags), BFW, FLAC.
> - Markup languages: HTML and XML.
> - Internet files: ARC
>
> If a file type is unknown the tool applies a generic adapter, which
>   extracts data that the host system 'knows' about any given file (such
>   as size, file name, and date created).

For more information, and to download visit [Metadata Extraction Tool](http://meta-extractor.sourceforge.net/)

<sup>Source:[Metadata Extraction Tool](http://meta-extractor.sourceforge.net/)</sup>

Comment: This program seems to only read the metadata, not remove it.

Comment: `Error: Writing of MKV files is not yet supported`

Answer (score 4):

First, install `exiftool` using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

Then, go into the directory with the JPEG files. If you want to remove metadata from every file in the directory, use

```
exiftool -all= *.jpg
```

For single file, use

```
exiftool -all= <filename>.jpg
```

Comment: This doesn't work for mp3 files

Comment: @baxx OP does not mentioned to use this with `.mp3` files

Comment: mp3 is a common file type that uses meta data and it's likely that someone will find this post as a result of searching ( I did )

Comment: Be careful, like the other answer, this only hides data and does not delete it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/308250/is-there-a-tool-for-removing-metadata/1331315#1331315