Remove docx metadata with Linux command line?
How to delete hidden information (metadata) from a Microsoft Word document (.docx) on a Linux system using terminal commands.
Can any suggest me some good tools for that as exiftool not supported docx files.

Well actually I found a duplicate, please try the method explained in the second answer to the linked question; after installing mat you want to run mat2 file.docx

Let me know if that worked for you: https://askubuntu.com/q/308250/380067

I closed the question as we haven't heard back from you (yet) and because the already existing question outlines at least 2 more different ways of tackling this issue, let us know if those didn't work for you and we'll reopen it.
